# How to get a list of files using jquery and phonegap from a remote server?

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova

I am trying to generate a list of downloadable text files from a website using phonegap and jquery. This list should be grabbed automatically when the "click me" button is clicked. So if another text file is added to the website and then the button is clicked, the newly added text file should also be in the list.. Right now, I should be alerted "success" if the files are grabbed, but I am getting alerted "error". I am very new to these technologies so I would appreciate it if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong here. This is what my index.html looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 

    function getFiles()
    {
        $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://samplewebsite.com/index.php",
dataType: "jsonp",
success: function(data) {
    alert("success");
 },
  error: function(){
    alert("error");
  }
});

 }      
   </script>

    <button onclick="getFiles();">clickme</button>

  </html>
```

Here's my index.php script on the server:

```
$files = array();
$dir = opendir('/tmp');
while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
    if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') {
        continue;
    }
    $files[] = $file;
}

header('Content-type: application/jsonp');
echo json_encode($files);
```

Comment: Just encoding the files as json doesn't make it JSONP, you need valid JSONP with a callback, otherwise it will fail.

Comment: Do you know how I would go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats what i would do (works like a charm):

1- Remove the `header('Content-type: application/jsonp');` on your .php

2- Use `$.getJSON()` instead of `$.ajax()`:

```
$.getJSON('http://samplewebsite.com/index.php', function(data) {
    alert(data);        
});
```

instead of

```
$.ajax({ ... });
```

Comment: I am getting an Access-Control-Allow error now. The exact error is:
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://samplewebsite.com/index.php. Origin http://127.0.0.1:8020 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. "

Comment: because, you cant be using 127.0.0.1/localhost on the url, the android emulator doesnt have access to localhost